# ASP.NET VB.NET Search button on masterpage change directory depending on membership role and current directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using masterpage, I have an input and button I need to be able to do navigation between the levels. I've tried

HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, and several other HttpContext ideas that do not work to get the current folder directory a user is in. How do I get the current directory a user is in?

For example, I need to know if user is in "level2" directory, or if in "Level3" directory, or if in root directory.

```
myurl.com/default.aspx
myurl.com/Level2/default.aspx
myurl.com/level2/Level3/default.aspx

If user is in Level3 then
Redirect here..
ElseIf user is in Root directory Then
Redirect here..
ElseIf user is in Level2 directory Then
Redirect here..
End If
```

Comment: Something like `Request.RawUrl.Split('/').Last();`

Comment: That gives result of the page currently on, not the directory/folder. For example, if I am in myurl.com/manage/default.aspx, the result is "default.aspx", whereas I would need "manage"

Comment: The above was just an example... `Request.RawUrl.Split('/')[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what VDWWD said:

```
string[] levels = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/');
```

If you `Split()` at the slash mark `('/')`, you get 4 segments

```
myurl.com/level2/Level3/default.aspx
     1      2      3         4
```

So:

```
if(levels.Length == 4)
{
    // you're at level 3. the level is the always the length-1.
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to get the name of the directory? or just the number position?

Comment: I got it, using the above code: For Each value In levels

                    If value = "Field" Then... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from the answer above:

```
Dim levels As String() = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split("/"c)
For Each value In Levels
   If value = "Field" Then
      Response.Redirect("~/Field/orders.aspx?OrderNo=" + qSearch.Text)
   ElseIf value = "Manage" Then
      Response.Redirect("~/Manage/orders.aspx?OrderNo=" + qSearch.Text)
   End If
Next
```